# Rotation number for homeomorphisms of a Lie group other than $S^1$

Tags: lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, lie-algebras

Let  $G$ be  a Lie  group  whose Lie  algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$  with exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$.

For  what kind of Lie group $G$ the  standard  process of  definition of rotation number for  circle  homeomorphisms work well?

Namely  for  every  homeomorphism $f:G\to G$ there is  a  homeomorphism $F:\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{g}$ with $\exp\circ F=f\circ \exp$  and the limit of $$\frac{F^n(x)-x}{n}$$ as  $n$ goes to infinity exists?

> This  limit  as  an element of  the  Lie  algebra would be called the rotation element.

What is  a  precise example for  which this  process works (other than $S^1$)?

Is it  equivalents to the  [exponential to be a covering map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190787/when-is-exponential-map-from-lie-algebra-to-lie-group-a-covering-map)?

**The  motivation:** I was thinking of  a possible generalization of Poincaré-Birkhoff theorem as  follows: We have  an area-preserving diffeomorphism on $[0,1]\times G$ where $G$ is a Lie group.
On the  boundary we get two rotation  elements as described above. Now assume that the  Lie  algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ consists of  matrices  and we may assume that these  rotation elements  are invertible  with opposite  sign  determinants.  Or we  may assume that a  reasonable  linear  functional, say trace, separate  these two  boundary rotation elements.  Then we may  state the  Poincaré-Birkhoff theorem in this new  setting and  think to its  possible  validity.

Comment: There's an existing notion of a "rotation set" which might be the generalization you're looking for. You can have more than one limit depending on your choice of $x$. It's already pretty interesting in the case of a torus!

Comment: @MartinM.W.  Thank  you!  could you please give me a reference. I googled "Rotation set"  and  Lie group  simultaneously but I could not  find materials in this regard

Comment: Here's a recent paper which has references to follow; note that this focuses on the torus case. (I'm not familiar with more general Lie group constructions, but a torus seems like the simplest entry point!) On the rotation sets of generic homeomorphisms on the torus, https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.00396

Comment: @AliTaghavi, I don't see how you can construct the map $F$ for an arbitrary $f$. The exponential map is not even surjective on certain Lie groups. On the other hand, you need to impose some restrictions on the map $f$ in order to guarantee the existence of the limit. For instance, in most of the cases $f$ must be homotopic to the identity.

Comment: @Alejandro  Thank you very much for your very interesting comment. I think about its details  and  also I try to remedy the post. regarding the surjectivity  we may add extra assumption "compact connected Lie group"

Comment: @Alejandro  In particular Iam thinking to  lifting  homeomorphism $f$  to $F$ you point out to.Thanks again for  your attention